# Weakly Normal Ultrafilters

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

A filter $F$ on $\lambda$ is weakly normal if and only if for all $f : \lambda \rightarrow \lambda$ such that $\{\xi < \lambda : f(\xi) < \xi\} \in F^+$, then there is some $\beta < \lambda$ and $X \in F^+$ such that $f(\xi) < \beta$ for all $\xi \in X$.

Let $\lambda \geq \kappa$ be a regular cardinal.

$S = \{\alpha < \lambda : cf(\alpha) < \kappa\}$

The question is: If $U$ is a $\kappa$-complete uniform weakly normal ultrafilter on $\lambda$, then $S \in U$.

---

This question comes from a proof of a theorem of Solovay that if $\kappa$ is a supercompact cardinal, then $\lambda^{<\kappa} = \lambda$ for all regular cardinal $\lambda \geq \kappa$. In the proof, if $\kappa$ is $\lambda$-supercompact, then there exists a $\kappa$-complete uniform weakly normal ultrafilter on $\lambda$. The proof claims that $S$ defined above is an element of $U$.

Something that may be relevant is that: Since $U$ is an ultrafilter $U = U^+$. $S$ is stationary in $\lambda$. And any uniform weakly normal filter contains the club subsets of $\lambda$. However this does not imply that $S \in U^+ = U$.

Thanks for any help or clarification on this problem.

Comment: The requirement that $U$ is $\kappa$-complete, uniform and weakly normal is not enough to get that $S\in U$ for a simple reason. If $\lambda$ is measurable and $\kappa<\lambda$ is regular, and $U$ is a normal ultrafilter over $\lambda$, then $U$ is also a $\kappa$-complete, uniform, weakly normal ultrafilter over $\lambda$. We know that $T=\{\alpha\in\lambda : \alpha$ is regular$\}\in U$, hence $S\notin U$ (that $T\in U$ can be seen by taking the embedding that stems from $U$, $j:V\to M$ and notice that $\lambda$ is regular in $M$). I don't think this answers the question though.

Comment: @Apostolos I don't see why $T \in U$. If $U$ is a normal ultrafilter, then $cf: \lambda \rightarrow \lambda$ is a regressive function. Hence by normality, there exists a $\beta < \lambda$ such that $X = cf^{-1}(\{\beta\}) \in U^+ = U$. Now suppose $U$ is uniform. Suppose $T \in U$. Then $T \cap X \in U$ has cardinality less than $\lambda$. This contradicts $U$ being uniform.

Comment: @Apostolos Also since a measureable cardinal is Mahlo, $T = \{\alpha \in \lambda : \alpha \text{ is regular }\}$ is stationary. Stationary subsets are not necessarily in $U$. (There are disjoint stationary subsets.)

Comment: If $U$ is a normal ultrafilter over $\lambda$, and $j:V\to M$ is the elementary embedding we get from $U$, then because $\lambda$ is regular and $M$ is a subclass of the universe, $\lambda$ is also regular in $M$. But $\lambda$ is represented by the identity function $\mathrm{id}$. This means that $$V^\lambda/U\models[\mathrm{id}]\textrm{ is regular.}$$ From this Los theorem gives that $\{\alpha\in\lambda : \mathrm{id}(\alpha)$ is regular$\}\in U$. That is $T\in U$.

Comment: Also, the cofinality function is not always regressive. It is only almost everywhere regressive if the set of regular cardinals is not in $U$. In the case of a normal ultrafilter (note here that I mean non-principal which implies that it is $\lambda$-complete and hence uniform) the set of singular cardinals is small.